# SVN client side hook

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hook

Does SVN have client-side hook support like in [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks)? I need a hook so that when I send a commit the browser opens a specific url.

Comment: "SVN" being the official command-line client?

Comment: yes, the oficial command-line client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Client-side hooks are a TortoiseSVN-specific feature.

Comment: Is there a intention to add this feature to svn client?

Answer (score 3):

Use an alias for SVN i.e. a python script that validates your inputs then forwards the call on to the real SVN. It might take a bit of work to get advanced functionality though, such as understanding changelist content, but there's libraries which can help and if you hunt around the internet someone has probably make something similar to what you want already.

http://pysvn.tigris.org/
http://top-frog.com/2009/04/23/client-side-pre-and-post-svn-hooks-with-unix-aliases/