# CruiseControl.NET does not execute Subversion hook scripts

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net, svn-hooks

On our CC.NET continuous integration server, I have implemented a Start Update hook script that works fine when I check out the source using TortoiseSVN. The hook script is meant to clean the working copy of all unversioned files before each build. However, when the build is executed, and the source gets updated, the hook script is not run.

How can I tell CruiseControl.NET to honor my hook scripts? We are using CC.NET 1.4.4.49. Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically setup a TortoiseSVN client side `Start Update hook` whereas the CC.Net would use a command line SVN client. CC.Net would have no knowledge of the hook you have setup. You can probably setup the cleaning of the unversioned files as a step in your build in CC.NET.

Comment: Oh, client-side hooks are a proprietary feature to TortoiseSVN, and not a part of Subverison?

Comment: @MetalSearGolid - yeah, it is specific to TortoiseSVN. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916098/svn-client-side-hook

Comment: I ended up just putting the script in CC.NET, which works just as well.